# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jute.OutputArchive with latest spring-kafka and spring-kafka-test 2.5.2

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-boot-test, spring-kafka-test

We have a spring boot app with spring-kafka and we are using embedded kafka for testing. We have upgraded Spring boot to 2.3.1 version and follow by latest spring kafka dependency which is 2.5.2. Now we are getting below error while executing test.
I have checked **zookeeper-jute** dependency is present in **zookeeper-3.5.7**.

When i am adding **zookeeper-jute** dependency in our pom, then it's working fine

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jute.OutputArchive
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_51]
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker$EmbeddedZookeeper.<init>(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:660) ~[spring-kafka-test-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.EmbeddedKafkaBroker.afterPropertiesSet(EmbeddedKafkaBroker.java:287) ~[spring-kafka-test-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1855) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1792) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407) ~[spring-beans-5.2.7.RELEASE.jar:5.2.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.customizeContext(EmbeddedKafkaContextCustomizer.java:116) ~[spring-kafka-test-2.5.2.RELEASE.jar:2.5.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextCustomizerAdapter.initialize(SpringBootContextLoader.java:302) ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.applyInitializers(SpringApplication.java:626) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:370) ~[spring-boot-2.3.1.RELEASE.jar:2.3.1.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be pulled in transitively by zookeeper itself; it is for me:

[image]

You should not have to manually declare it in your pom; so perhaps some maven problem?

Comment: Thanks Gary. Yes, the issue is with our maven repository